# Automapper adding valueTransformer to the "dictionary to object" mapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map a Dictionary to a POCO with the builtin mapper and apply an additional transformation on strings with a global ValueTransformer:

```
class MyPoco
{
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
}
```

The mapper call:

```
            var source = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "StringValue", "abc" }
            };

            var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.ValueTransformers.Add<string>(dest => dest + "!!!");
                })
                .CreateMapper();

            var poco = mapper.Map<MyPoco>(source);
            Assert.Equal("abc!!!", poco.StringValue);
```

After the mapping call the `poco.StringValue` equals to 'abc' and the configured ValueTransfomer is never called. Am I missing something?

Comment: You cannot. You could have a map from string to string, but that would apply everywhere.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, is it a limitation of the Dictionary object mapper?

Comment: No, not really, mappers are not maps. Transformers only apply to maps. Mappers are a kind of built in maps.